# In hardhat unit testing how do you assert multiple return values from a contract

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I have this solidity contract function that returns multiple values of multiple types. How do I assert them in my unit tests?

I tried something like
var [x, y] = await contractA.getAll()
etc. but that doesn’t work.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the Solidity return variables are not named, you can access them using their position indexes.

```
function getAll() external pure returns (uint8, bool) {
    return (1, true);
}
```

```
const returnedValues = await contract.getAll(); // [ 1, true ]
const number = returnedValues[0];
const status = returnedValues[1];
```

And if they are named, you can also access them with object keys.

```
function getAll() external pure returns (uint8 number, bool status) {
    return (1, true);
}
```

```
const returnedValues = await contract.getAll(); // [ 1, true, number: 1, status: true ]
const number = returnedValues.number;
const status = returnedValues.status;
```